# No Argument Here... PHP Warning: The argument should be an array... Where is this error coming from in PHP script for WP posting?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, wordpress, arguments

I have wordpress installed and a script that makes posts out of csv files. It has been working for months, but now is not and showing the below error in the error files.

[17-Nov-2013 14:30:03] PHP Warning:  array_values() [function.array-values]: The argument should be an array in /path/_adder.php on line 80

What is strange is that it works well in one installation and it does not work in another. Both WP set ups are the same, same domain. Why would I get this error in one subdomain but not the other? With identical file.csv and _adder.php

Earlier today the script was giving the below error as it was out of memory.

[17-Nov-2013 11:00:05] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8388608 bytes) in /path/_adder.php on line 16

So I added `ini_set('memory_limit','256M');` to the top of the script. This solved the memory problem, but now I am getting the array error.

Any suggestions, comments or tips? Help is very much appreciated with this.

Below is complete text of _adder.php

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit','256M');

require_once('wp-config.php');

$siteurl = get_site_url();


function clearer($str) {
  //$str = iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-8//IGNORE", $str);
  $str = utf8_encode($str);
  $str = str_replace("’", "'", $str);
  $str = str_replace("–", "-", $str);
  return htmlspecialchars($str);
}

//file read
if(file_exists("file.csv")) $csv_lines  = file("file.csv");
if(is_array($csv_lines)) {

  $cnt = 15;
  for($i = 0; $i < $cnt; $i++) {
    $line = $csv_lines[$i];
    $line = trim($line);
    $first_char = true;
    $col_num = 0;
    $length = strlen($line);
    for($b = 0; $b < $length; $b++) {
      if($skip_char != true) {
        $process = true;
        if($first_char == true) {
          if($line[$b] == '"') {
            $terminator = '",';
            $process = false;
          }else
            $terminator = ',';
          $first_char = false;
        }

        if($line[$b] == '"'){
          $next_char = $line[$b + 1];
          if($next_char == '"')
            $skip_char = true;
          elseif($next_char == ',') {
            if($terminator == '",') {
              $first_char = true;
              $process = false;
              $skip_char = true;
            }
          }
        }

        if($process == true){
          if($line[$b] == ',') {
             if($terminator == ',') {
                $first_char = true;
                $process = false;
             }
          }
        }

        if($process == true)
          $column .= $line[$b];

        if($b == ($length - 1)) {
          $first_char = true;
        }

        if($first_char == true) {
          $values[$i][$col_num] = $column;
          $column = '';
          $col_num++;
        }
      }
      else
        $skip_char = false;
    }
  }

  $values = array_values($values);
  //print_r($values);

  /*************************************************/

  if(is_array($values)) {
    //file.csv read
    for($i = 0; $i < count($values); $i++) {
      unset($post);

      //check duplicate
      //$wpdb->show_errors();
      $wpdb->query("SELECT `ID` FROM `" . $wpdb->prefix . "posts`
                            WHERE `post_title` = '".clearer($values[$i][0])."' AND `post_status` = 'publish'");
        //echo $wpdb->num_rows;

      if($values[$i][0] != "Name" && $values[$i][0] != "" && $wpdb->num_rows == 0) {
        $post['name'] = clearer($values[$i][0]);
        $post['Address'] = clearer($values[$i][1]);
        $post['City'] = clearer($values[$i][2]);
        $post['Categories'] = $values[$i][3];
        $post['Tags'] = $values[$i][4];
        $post['Top_image'] = $values[$i][5];
        $post['Body_text'] = clearer($values[$i][6]);

        //details
        for($k = 7; $k <= 56; $k++) {
          $values[$i][$k] != '' ? $post['details'] .= "<em>".clearer($values[$i][$k])."</em>\r\n" : '';
        }

        //cats
        $categoryes = explode(";", $post['Categories']);
        foreach($categoryes AS $category_name) {
          $term = term_exists($category_name, 'category');
          if (is_array($term)) {
            //category exist
            $cats[] = $term['term_id'];
          }else{
            //add category
            wp_insert_term( $category_name, 'category' );
            $term = term_exists($category_name, 'category');
            $cats[] = $term['term_id'];
          }
        }

        //top image
        if($post['Top_image'] != "") {
          $im_name = md5($post['Top_image']).'.jpg';

          $im = @imagecreatefromjpeg($post['Top_image']); 
          if ($im) {
            imagejpeg($im, ABSPATH.'images/'.$im_name);
            $post['topimage'] = '<img class="alignnone size-full" src="'.$siteurl.'/images/'.$im_name.'" alt="" />';
          }
        }

        //bottom images
        for($k = 57; $k <= 76; $k++) {
          if($values[$i][$k] != '') {
            $im_name = md5($values[$i][$k]).'.jpg';

            $im = @imagecreatefromjpeg($values[$i][$k]);
            if ($im) {
              imagejpeg($im, ABSPATH.'images/'.$im_name);
              $post['images'] .= '<a href="'.$siteurl.'/images/'.$im_name.'"><img class="alignnone size-full" src="'.$siteurl.'/images/'.$im_name.'" alt="" /></a>';
            }
          }
        }

        $post = array_map( 'stripslashes_deep', $post );

        //print_r($post);

        //post created
        $my_post = array (
           'post_title' => $post['name'],
           'post_content' => '
              <em>Address: '.$post['Address'].'</em>
              '.$post['topimage'].'
              '.$post['Body_text'].'
              <!--more-->
              '.$post['details'].'
              '.$post['images'].'
           ',
           'post_status' => 'publish',
           'post_author' => 1,
           'post_category' => $cats
        );
        unset($cats);

        //add post
        //echo "ID:" .
        $postid = wp_insert_post($my_post); //post ID

        //tags
        wp_set_post_tags( $postid, str_replace(';',',',$post['Tags']), true ); //tags

        echo $post['name']. ' - added. ';

        //google coords
        $address = preg_replace("!\((.*?)\)!si", " ", $post['Address']).', '.$post['City'];
        $json = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://hicon.by/temp/googlegeo.php?address='.urlencode($address)));
        //print_r($json);

        if($json->status == "OK") {
          //нашло адрес
          $google['status'] = $json->status;

          $params = $json->results[0]->address_components;
          if(is_array($params)) {
            foreach($params AS $id => $p) {
              if($p->types[0] == 'locality') $google['locality_name'] = $p->short_name;
              if($p->types[0] == 'administrative_area_level_2') $google['sub_admin_code'] = $p->short_name;
              if($p->types[0] == 'administrative_area_level_1') $google['admin_code'] = $p->short_name;
              if($p->types[0] == 'country') $google['country_code'] = $p->short_name;
              if($p->types[0] == 'postal_code') $google['postal_code'] = $p->short_name;
            }
          }
          $google['address'] = $json->results[0]->formatted_address;
          $google['location']['lat'] = $json->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
          $google['location']['lng'] = $json->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;

          //print_r($params);

          //print_r($google);

          //insert into DB
          $insert_code = $wpdb->insert( $wpdb->prefix . 'geo_mashup_locations',
                                        array( 'lat' => $google['location']['lat'], 'lng' => $google['location']['lng'], 'address' => $google['address'],
                                               'saved_name' => $post['name'], 'postal_code' => $google['postal_code'],
                                               'country_code' => $google['country_code'], 'admin_code' => $google['admin_code'],
                                               'sub_admin_code' => $google['sub_admin_code'], 'locality_name' => $google['locality_name'] ),
                                        array( '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s' )
                                      );
          if($insert_code) {
            $google_code_id = $wpdb->insert_id;
            $geo_date = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );
            $wpdb->insert(
              $wpdb->prefix . 'geo_mashup_location_relationships',
              array( 'object_name' => 'post', 'object_id' => $postid, 'location_id' => $google_code_id, 'geo_date' => $geo_date ),
              array( '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s' )
            );
          }else{
            //can't insert data
          }

          echo ' address added.<br />';

        }else{
          //echo $json->status;
        }

      }
    } //$values end (for)
  }
}else{
  //not found file.csv
  echo 'not found file.csv';
}

$input = explode("\n", file_get_contents("file.csv"));
foreach ($input as $line) {
 // process all lines.
}

// This function removes first $CNT elements.
// More info:
// http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php
$output = array_slice($input, $cnt);
file_put_contents("file.csv", implode("\n", $output));

?>
<html>
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
 CSV: <input name="file" type="file" />
 <input type="submit" value="Send File" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not intializing `$value` anywhere in your script. So, if the statement `if($first_char == true)` returns `FALSE`, you'll be trying to call [`array_values()`](http://php.net/array_values) on an empty variable, hence causing the error that you're seeing now.

To resolve this issue, add the following at the top:

```
$value = array();
```

Now, even if the `if` statement evaluates to `FALSE`, you'll be calling `array_values()` on an (empty) array and you can avoid the error.

Comment: What is strange is that it works in one installation and it does not work in another. Both WP set ups are the same, same domain. Why would I get this error in one subdomain but not the other? With identical file.csv and _adder.php

Comment: I added $value = array(); and am getting the same error message.

Comment: @user586011: I'm sorry, it's `$values` (with the `s`) -- it was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error in this code.

```
$values = array_values($values);
```

The `$values` is not defined anywhere and thus you are getting the warning. The `array_values()`  expects an array as an input and returns array as output. [*But nothing is been sent to this function*]